# Flutter Dropdown - different Widgets/Design for Item List and selected Item

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I need a DropDown where the items in the list have more information than shown in the view of the selected element.

For example: I have a DropDown based of a List that includes an object that has two properties.

```
class MyElement {
   String infoA;
   String infoB;
}
```

At the Dropdown list self, I would like to see both Information. For example represented by a Text(f"$infoA - $infoB").
But for the Item that is shown as selected Item I wan't only Text(f"$infoA").

So is there a way to define two different DropDownMenuItems, depending on if they are in the List or if they are shown in the selected field?